# How to get stack trace in google actions logs, because 'final_response' must be set is useless

Tags: debugging, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The debugging in actions on google is hell. The only usefull thing to do is if you debug in **Dialogflow test console**, because there you can see exactly where it went wrong. But here you just get this **MalformedResponse: 'final_response' must be set.** Is there any way to print out **console.log** so you can see at least in **Logs Viewer** what went through and what didn't?

Because from this, you can't see anything what went wrong except that conv.ask didn't execute or am i missing something?

```
 insertId: "id"  
 labels: {
  channel: "preview"   
  querystream: "GOOGLE_USER"   
  source: "JSON_RESPONSE_VALIDATION"   
 }
 logName: "projects/0/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2018-08-27T08:01:46.632208192Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   action_id: "actions.intent.TEXT"    
   project_id: "avant2goassistant"    
   version_id: ""    
  }
  type: "assistant_action"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "MalformedResponse: 'final_response' must be set"  
 timestamp: "2018-08-27T08:01:46.605934393Z"  
 trace: "projects/0/traces/0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of places to investigate if you get this error.

First check the obvious - that your Intent has fulfillment enabled. At the bottom of your Intent, make sure "Enable webhook call for this intent" is turned on.

[image]

If you're sure about that, check the logs for your webhook. You haven't specified how or where your webhook is running, so I can't provide detailed guidance on that, but if you're using the Dialogflow built in editor, you can check out the logs in Firebase. Make sure there isn't an error being thrown.

I often run testing locally (using `firebase serve --only functions`) and use [ngrok](https://ngrok.io/) to provide a secure tunnel. ngrok also provides a protocol inspector which will let you look at the response you're sending back to Dialogflow.

If you're still having issues, you may wish to turn on Dialogflow logging to Google Cloud. This is on the settings screen (under the gear icon for your project) and towards the bottom. It is off by default - turn it on, and you can follow the link there to see where the logs are. This will show you what is sent to your fulfillment and what you get back.

[image]

Much of this information is also in the "Response" and "Debug" tabs in the Actions on Google simulator. You can also look there (or post them on StackOverflow) if you still need help.

Using the Dialogflow simulator isn't sufficient for debugging Actions - the AoG environment sends additional information that the Dialogflow simulator doesn't.

Comment: I didn't know about those log settings, thank you :). I'm using local webhooks and usually I deploy them with firebase deploy with every change and test them out that way.

Comment: You're welcome! If you're doing it locally, certainly check out `firebase serve --only functions` which I've added to my notes, and look into ngrok. Lots of additional info. If this has helped, accepting and/or upvoting the answer are always appreciated.

Comment: You got it, you really helped me :)